# Is it expensive to create a new Drools KnowledgeBase every time a rule needs to be evaluated?

Tags: drools

I have a situation where for each product I have a different rule.

Thus, I will have 1 drl per each product.

Consequently, as far I understand I have a choice:

1. add all those knowledge packages into a single KnowledgeBase.

and then let Drools match the right rule using the id of the product.

```
when 

avs : AvailabilityStatus( available == true, quantity <= 50, productId = 7899 ) 

then    

avs.setDiscountRate("0.65");

end
```

1. create a new KnowledgeBase for each product i.e. for 50 products, 50 KnowledgeBases with just one drl loaded for each.

In my web app each request requires a new evaluation of the rules for the product.

I don't know which approach is more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The KnowledgeBase is a very, very expensive object to instantiate, so I wouldn't create one each time a rule needs to be evaluated.

I think the first approach you mentioned is better (to have all rules into one drl). This also leaves the option open to do rules across products (imagine if you want to add price rules, and you want to model a *buy 2, get the 3rd free*).

There's a third approach, in which you can still have one drl per product, but you load all of them in the same knowledge base. This is similar to the [sigle responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), but applied to the rules.

Comment: Augusto, thank you so much for the answer. You confirmed my suspicion about the expense of creating a large number of kbs.

Comment: But I didn't quite get the difference between the approach two and three. Is there a practical difference when the rules when...then...end are all in the same file vs loaded into the same knowledge base through different .drls ?

How does, Drools know (is it Rete) which rules to execute so it is efficient? If I have 100K products and 5 rules for each product, is Drools even going to be an option for me i.e. how long will it take to match the right rule?

Comment: that's the whole idea behind the Rete Algorithm, if you have 500k rules about your products buy only 5 rules for a specific product the algorithm is smart enough to only evaluate the 5 rules related with your specific product, instead of evaluating the whole 500k. Take a look at my blog posts, trying to explain the algorithm behavior: http://salaboy.com/tag/rete/

Comment: Salaboy, thank you. Just started with Drools, I've seen your contributions to the community so I'll def. read your blog. I knew of the algorithm as you can tell from my previous comment but I didn't read in detail; I thought may be you guys would point me at an optimization or rules feature such as ruleflow-group.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to write a rule per your product it is likely that you have multiple rules that have the same kind of LHS with only parameter changes, eg

```
when 
  avs : AvailabilityStatus( available == true, quantity <= 50, productId = 7899 ) 
then
  //update
```

then you can consider using a decision table. Drools can generate rules itself. [As stated in users guide](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.4.0.Final/drools-expert-docs/html/ch02.html)

Comment: @alicox Thank you, you are absolutely correct in your guess and I did see decision table in the documentation. I will post a separate question where I will go into more detail about the conditions of my project. I think it will be more appropriate to discuss there which approaches are appropriate and whether in fact Drools is a good candidate in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create just one knowledge base and store the binary packages in the file system. When you want to add a new rule, you regenerate the binary package. Don't create a drl per rule, that doesn't make any sense. 
Cheers

Comment: Thank you. I'm clear on the one knowledge base and as you can tell from the question I was instinctively sure that this would be the answer. However, I'm not sure what you are referring to when you mention binary packages.
My heuristic and I'm gonna mention since it may help others in the future is the following:
One) Capture user input
Two) Use a freemarker template to generate a drools rule
Three) Add that rule to the existing kbase
kbuilder.add(ResourceFactory.newFileResource(newlyAssembledDRL), ResourceType.DRL);
kbase.addKnowledgePackages(kbuilder.getKnowledgePackages());

Comment: The question is what will happen with the existing sessions? Are you planning to re generate the sessions each time that you add a rule? The binary package that I was mentioning is the result of kbuilder.getKnowledgePackages(), you can write that to the filesystem and you will not need to recompile your rules again. Cheers

Comment: You reply about sessions makes me a little concerned. I am not sure how drools works in a multithreaded environment. But I'm sure that's a big and interesting topic on its own. I am creating ksession = kbase.newStatefulKnowledgeSession(); for every every new httprequest. I don't know what is going to happen to the sessions that exist while the knowledgebase is being updated with a new knowledge package. I didn't test for it. I should but I'm not seeing how saving kbuilder.getKnowldegePackages() to disk makes a difference. Could you explain?